# Object logged to Chrome console has a nonexistent property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object

I'm trying to return an object response from a function, but while I was debugging in the Chrome dev tools, I noticed that it had a property that it shouldn't. I removed things from the response until it was eventually just an empty object, followed immediately by a console.log:

```
const result = {};
console.log(result);
```

But it still shows up in the Chrome console with the extra property:

```
{
    layerId: 1
}
```

When I try `console.log(result.layerId)`, it returns `undefined`. If I stringify it with `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))`, it correctly logs `{}`.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: impossible to tell from what is provided. Show code that produces the issue. Might be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays

Comment: I have literally included all of the code. It is a new constant, with a unique name, followed immediately by a console.log.

Comment: Nothing else should be modifying this result object to inject 'layerId', but I'll be going through to make sure it isn't a shallow copy problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe result object had been used in the console, still saving constant result. Does it still happen when you try it on new tab/window console?

Comment: I tried a new tab, then restarting the browser along with clearing the cache, and also renaming the constant. Still showing up!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any debugging chrome extensions loaded/running?  Some of these attach properties to the console/objects in order for the tool to run.  Many different possibilities, so to rule that out, can you disable extensions and see if it persists?

Comment: No need--I have no extensions at all, this is a plain Chrome install on the latest version. 'layerId' is a property I use elsewhere, so I recognize it, but in my test case this is a new constant, with a unique name, that is being logged immediately after creation.